# Xml as a string

Tags: python

How to load a xml file as a string? I would like to see a full entite content with all tags.

I've found the ways how to load a file with decoding, but it's not something that I need at the first step.

Comment: Open the file as a basic txt file and read it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to open the XML file as a basic text file and read its content like that:

```py
with open("xml_file.xml", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    content = f.read()
print(content)
```